# What is the purpose of try with resource block in java?

Tags: java, java-7, try-catch-finally

What is the purpose of try with resource block in java. I understands that it takes an `AutoCloseable` object reference like `Inputstream`, which it case close .

I want to know what the advantage of this construct. The same we are able to achieve by closing resources in finally block.

```
try(? extends AutoCloseable){
}
```

Comment: Java guarantees that the resources inside the `try` clause will be closed automatically regardless of what happens (save a `System.exit()`).

Comment: Have you read the [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)? If not, please read it. If you have, please highlight which bit is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same thing by closing resources in a `finally` block.  Using try-with-resource is just slightly less verbose - it reduces the need for boilerplate code for resource management all over the place.